# How to add bitten-slave as a Windows service

Tags: windows-services, service, continuous-integration

As Part of setting up continuous integration using bitten, I would like to set up some bitten-slaves on windows. However, bitten documentation lacks instructions on how to register bitten slave as a service.

Looking at Microsoft's documentation on [How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192), I've tried the following:

```
sc create bitten-slave binPath= "C:\Python26\Scripts\bitten-slave.exe --verbose 
--log=C:\dev\bitten.log http://svn/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/builds"
```

The service was indeed created. But trying to start it, I get the following error:

> The bitten-slave service failed to
>   start due to the following error:  The
>   service did not respond to the start
>   or control request in a timely
>   fashion.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any random program can't run as a service in Windows, the application needs to be [specially written](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) to talk to the service controller.

> An application that wants to be a service needs to first be written in such a way that it can handle start, stop, and pause messages from the Service Control Manager.

However, Microsoft does provide a generic service wrapper, [SRVANY](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890), which can be used to run an arbitrary program as a service.  I use SRVANY to run several python scripts as services, so it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://bitten.edgewall.org/wiki/BittenSlaveDaemonWindows) on the Bitten wiki describes a simple Python script that can be configured as a scheduled task to ensure the Bitten slave is kept running.